# Java / C# - Array[][] complexity task

Tags: c#, java, arrays, algorithm, task

I'm dealing with some problematic complexity question via my university:

Program input : A `n x n` `Array[][]` that is filled with either `0` or `1`.

DEFINITION: Define `k` as a **SINK** if in the `k` row all the values are `0`, and in the `k` column all the values are `1` (except `[k][k]` itself which needs to be `0`)

Program output : Is there a k number that is a **SINK**? If so, return`k`, else return `-1`.

Example :

[image: example]

On Arr A k=3 is a SINK, on Arr B there in no SINK, so -1 is returned.

The main problem with this task is that the complexity of the program must be below `O(n^2)` , I have managed to solve this with that complexity, going over the oblique line summing the rows&columns. I haven't find a way to solve this with `O(logn)` or `O(n)`. Also the task prevents you from using another Array[] (Due to memory complexity). Can anyone drop any light on that matter? thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the constraint on memory complexity? Since O(n^2) is already used, an additional O(n) should not hurt.

Comment: I have managed to solve this with O(n^2) but that is not the task's requirements. It needs to be with less than that. If you can find a way to solve this using an O(n) memory complexity (without on-time O(n^2) ) it will also be very helpful.

Comment: What is your input? 2d array of numbers? or table stored like a string?

Comment: 2D array of numbers(which are 0s or 1s)

Comment: We did not yet study Lists/ArrayLists, is there a way around this ?

Comment: Hm, I'v never been good at calculating `O`. What I would do is: have a list of `n` possible `k`s (all initialized to be valid) now go column by column (for still valid `k`s). If I find a cell in that column which is `0` but the row-ID != column-ID, I mark that column-ID (k) as invalid. If there is no valid `k` left after all the columns, then return `-1`, else go through each valid `k` row and look if the sum of that row is zero. Dunno what complexity that is, though, or if there is a better algorithm.

Comment: Belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Corak in worst case there is a O(n^2) complexity too. But if there is more then one valid `k` you can return `-1` then the worst case is O(2n)

Comment: Possible solution that I can see is: 1. Iterate from the top left corner of the matrix, downwards. 2. If you come across at least 2 zeros then move to the next column and start from the row of 1st zero accessed. 3. If you found only 1 zero in a column then traverse the zero row to see if you found the sink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make explicit the answer harold links to in the OP's comments: start yourself off with a list of all `n` indices, `S = {0, 1, .., n-1}`. These are our candidates for sinks. At each step, we're going to eliminate one of them.

1. Consider the first two elements of `S`, say `i` and `j`.
2. Check whether `A[i, j]` is 1.

   - If it is, remove `i` from S (because the *i* th row isn't all 0s, so `i` can't be our sink )
   - If it isn't, remove `j` from S (because the *j* th column isn't all 1s, so `j` can't be our sink)
3. If there're still two or more elements in S, go back to Step 1.
4. When we get to the last element, say `k`, check whether the *k* th row is all zero and the *k* th column (other than `A[k,k]`) are all ones.

   - If they are, `k` is a sink and you can return it.
   - If they aren't, the matrix does not have a sink and you can return `-1`.

There are `n` elements in `S` to begin with, each step eliminates one of them and each step takes constant time, so it's *O(n)* overall.

You mention you don't want to use a second array. If that really is strict, you can just use two integers instead, one representing the "survivor" from the last step and one representing how far into the sequence *0, 1, .., n-1* you are.

I've never seen this algorithm before and I'm quite impressed with it's simplicity. Cheers.

Comment: Seems great, thank you very much. I will go ahead and try it out ! Can you deeply explain how to solve this with two integers?

Comment: Let's call the two integers `survivor` and `challenger`. Initialize them as `survivor = 0, challenger = 1`. If `A[survivor, challenger] == 1`, then you set `survivor = challenger` (because `survivor` can't be the sink as it has a 1 in its row) and increment `challenger`. If `A[survivor, challenger] == 0`, then you just increment `challenger` (because `challenger` can't be the sink as it has a 0 in its column). When `challenger == n`, you're done, and the current `survivor` is the only possible sink, which you then verify.